# Can't remove object from array

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I have two classes.
One class is MyListImpl. Here i have two methods Remove and Add. I'm doing smth like ArrayList realization. My `remove(Object o)` method doesn't work correctly. It gives me NullPointer. How to do that objects from my array will be deleted correctly?

```
        public class MyListImpl implements MyList, ListIterable {

        private Object[] array = new Object[8];

@Override
    public void add(Object e) {

        int mainArraySize = this.array.length;
        if (this.iterator < mainArraySize) {
            this.array[this.iterator] = e;
            this.iterator++;

        } else {
            Object[] arrayCopy = new Object[mainArraySize + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
                arrayCopy[i] = this.array[i];
            }
            arrayCopy[mainArraySize] = e;
            this.array = arrayCopy;
        }
    }




    @Override
        public boolean remove(Object o) {
            // Removing object from array
                int j = 0;
                Object[] arr = new Object[this.array.length-1];
                System.out.println(arr.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
                    if (this.array[i].toString().equals(o.toString())!=true) {
                        arr[j] = this.array[i];
                        j += 1; 
                    }

                }

                return true;
            }
```

Here is my Demo class

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyListImpl con = new MyListImpl();

        con.add("A");
        con.add("P");
        con.add("Z");
        con.add("1");
        con.add("53");
        con.remove("P");
}
}
```

Comment: One, you are using toString() in comparision, which will not work for all kinds of objects. Two, you are removing the element from temporary array, but the orginal array (this.array) remains unchanged.

Comment: Try debugging to see what actually o.toString() returns. I think this `this.array[i].toString().equals(o.toString())` will always be true.

Comment: Side note: it seems to be rather ... wrong (?) to allow your data structure to work with "Object"s ... to then call toString() on them; when making comparisons. And that is probably also your problem: are you sure that all your array elements are != null? And that the incoming o is always != null?!

Comment: You aren't saving `arr` anywhere (it's a local variable). You probably meant to add `this.array = arr;` before `return true;` And you have an array with `null`s in it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, thanx! I forgot it. but how to compare two elements of Object class?

Comment: @Serg ShapovalIf In order to compare, assuming that your object has the `equals` method overridden, you can use it like `object1.equals(object2)`. If you are really using Object, it has the equals method implemented by default.